# operator== having a different behavior between reference and copy

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading

let's imagine a simple class such as this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int b) : bar(b) {}
    int bar;

    friend bool operator==(const Foo& l, const Foo& r); 
};

bool operator==(const Foo& l, const Foo& r) {
    return l.bar == r.bar;
}
```

I'm having a weird behaviour with the operator== where comparing an object with another with the same `bar` value doesn't return true.

To understand, consider this code:

```
Foo& findRef(int barToFind); //Assume those functions works correctly
Foo findCopy(int barToFind);

Foo f1(1);

Foo& fRef = findRef(1);
Foo fCopy = findCopy(1);

f1 == fRef; //Will evaluate to false
f1 == fCopy; //Will evaluate to true
```

Why is that? Did I miss something? This code was tested on Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you

Edit: Provided is the findRef function. The findCopy is exactly the same, except it doesn't return a reference. MyArray is assured to live for the duration of the program.

```
Foo& findRef(int bar) {
    //MyArray of type std::vector<Foo>
    auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(MyArray), std::end(MyArray), [=](const Foo& f){ return f.bar == bar; });
    assert(it != std::end(MyArray));

    return *it;
}
```

Comment: I don't think we *can* assume that function works correctly. I think you have [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Comment: @chris I can still access all methods and variable of those classes. It basically find just an object in an array and return it. Verified by an assert.

Comment: You don't have me convinced. Undefined behaviour can "work", and often does.

Comment: @chris I provided the findRed method if you'd like.

Comment: Okay well that should work as long as `MyArray` lives long enough.

Comment: You probably return a reference to a locally defined object and all bets are off. To convince yourself, declare `const Foo& fRef = findRef(1);`, you can bound const references to temporaries and keep the temporary alive. Your code will probably work.

Comment: Seeing `Foo f1(1);`: You messed up constructors/assignment of Foo

Comment: This almost certainly points to the value returned by reference from ``findRef`` not staying alive and this giving you undefined behavior.

Comment: @chris It does live long enough. It dies with the end of the program.

Comment: We need to see more code to find the problem. There are a lot of good guesses above, and any one of them might be the issue. Logging `f1.bar`, `fRef.bar`, and `fCopy.bar` might help.

Comment: Also, this can be very easily tested by simply printing out the value of ``fRef.bar`` and seeing if it's what you expect it to be, unless of course this is a very simplified example and that's not a practical thing to do.

Comment: @DieterLücking I added the constructor, just forgot to put it originally.

Logging the value all gives me 1.

Comment: Running it on ideone with C++11 output both to true. Might be a bug in VS2013? See http://ideone.com/baDde5

Comment: @Rosme I am running VS2013 Update 1, and running your code prints `true` for both.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Odd...all I can think is that there is something wrong in the rest of my code. I'm going to be searching and try to find the source. Most probably some UB for some reason.

Comment: Please post a complete runnable program that reproduces the bug.

Comment: @n.m. I can't. I'll dig more into my code. I definitely have something wrong in my code that causes this odd behaviour. (Unrelated directly, but should I just delete this question since it doesn't seem to be what I thought it was?)